# C# WPF ComboBox - Allow item to be selected only once per list

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, observablecollection

I use C#, WPF and try to use MVVM.  So I have an ObservableCollection of MyObjects.  The list is rendered into a DataGrid, and one property of MyObject is a static list of items which is shown in a ComboBoxes in each row.

Now I would like to select an item in one row in this combobox, and if it was selected in another row before, the last selection has to be removed to the default value. How can I manage this? My MyObjectViewModel knows about the change of its 'own" combobox but how can it tell the MainViewModel (which holds the ObservableCollection of MyObjects) to change the last selected ComboBox item from another MyObject object?

Comment: You said the list is static, right?  So shouldn't you be able to just remove the selected item, and it will update for all rows automatically?

Comment: I don't want it to be removed from the list; if there is another ComboBox yet which was selected with this item before, this' ComboBox selection has to be removed.

Comment: Why don't you use a List for all items "AllItems", one for the selected items "SeledtedItems" and a third one with the available items "AvailableItems", the latter being a caluclation of "AllItems" minus "SelectedItems". This list is the one you bind to your ComboBoxes' ItemsSource.

Whenever "SelectedItems" changes fire a NotifyPropertyChanged on "AvailableItems" too.

Comment: @SvenG But if it's bound to "AvailableItems", that would remove the selected item from the ComboBox in each row.  I think Op is saying if an item is selected, it should remain there in that row.

Comment: @SvenG maybe if you had a third property in each row -- "SelectedItem" -- and add that to the binding of "AvailableItems" ?

Comment: @dbaseman : Yes you're right, haven't thought about that, adding a "SelectedItem" and adding it to the set could work, Good one !

Comment: Thanks for all answers but I'm not sure how to implement your solution. How can I add the "AvailableItems" list AND a property "SelectedItem" at once to the ComboBox binding (in XAML)?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to change your binding focus to ListCollectionViews as this will allow you to manage the cursor. An example is below:

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Data;

    namespace BindingSample
    {
        public class ViewModel
        {
            private string[] _items = new[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };

            public ViewModel()
            {
                List1 = new ListCollectionView(_items);
                List2 = new ListCollectionView(_items);
                List3 = new ListCollectionView(_items);

                List1.CurrentChanged += (sender, args) => SyncSelections(List1);
                List2.CurrentChanged += (sender, args) => SyncSelections(List2);
                List3.CurrentChanged += (sender, args) => SyncSelections(List3);
            }

            public ListCollectionView List1 { get; set; }

            public ListCollectionView List2 { get; set; }

            public ListCollectionView List3 { get; set; }

            private void SyncSelections(ListCollectionView activeSelection)
            {
                foreach (ListCollectionView view in new[] { List1, List2, List3 })
                {
                    if (view != activeSelection && view.CurrentItem == activeSelection.CurrentItem)
                        view.MoveCurrentTo(null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

View

```
<Window x:Class="ContextMenuSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List1}" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List2}" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List3}" />        
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This will allow you to only have one item selected. It's hard-coded for now but can be easily made more flexible for additional lists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but following your way I would need the same list in every object. Isn't it possible to do this with a static list (one list for all objects)?

Comment: There is only only one actual list, as defined in the _items variable. List1, List2 & List3 are just views of this static data source.